# No public execute() in class org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.Arg

Tags: ant, jenkins, jmeter

Need help regarding the above mentioned error.
When i try to pass parameter from jenkins to ant I get the following error:

```
"No public execute() in class org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.Arg"
```

As I am new to jenkins ant integration I don't have much idea.
Any suggestions will be of great help.

My ant script is:

```
<project basedir=".">

    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="jmeter-home" location="D:/apache-jmeter-2.7"/>
    <property name="THREADS" value="${env.THREADS}"/>

    <path id="ant.jmeter.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${jmeter-home}/extras/ant-jmeter-1.0.9.jar" />
    </path>

    <taskdef
        name="jmeter"
        classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"
        classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath" />
    <taskdef 
        name="jvmarg" 
        classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.Arg" 
        classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath"/>

    <target name="clean">
       <delete dir="results"/>
       <delete file="jmeter.log"/>
       <mkdir dir="results/jtl"/>
       <mkdir dir="results/html"/>
   </target>

   <target name="Product" depends="clean" >
       <jmeter jmeterhome="d:/apache-jmeter-2.7"
               resultlogdir="results/jtl"
               testplan="D:\Program Files\....\Test.jmx" />
       <jvmarg value ="-DTHREADS"/>
       <xslt
           in="${basedir}/results/jtl/Test.jtl"
           out="${basedir}/results/html/Test.xml"
           style="${jmeter-home}/extras/jmeter-results-report_21.xsl"/>
   </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't to define additionally `jvmarg` taskdef.

1. You have declared property for THREADS:

   > ```
   > <property name="THREADS" value="${env.THREADS}"/>
   > ```
2. In `jmeter` task set additionally

   > ```
   > <property name="jmeter.threads" value="${THREADS}"/>
   > ```
3. Set required number of threads in ant's command line:

   > ```
   > ant -f build.xml -DTHREADS=N
   > ```

As well you can possibly use [`jmeterarg` nested element](http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php):

> **jmeterarg** Use to specify additional JMeter command line arguments. The
>   only attribute is value.

Comment: build.xml:28: Problem: failed to create task or type jvmarg
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

If done as you said its showing error like this.
PS:when I am executing the ant script from jenkins its showing this error

Comment: Well, once more: 1. remove 'jvmarg' taskdef from your build.xml. 2. Add and define 'property' to your 'jmeter' task as above. 3. Use '-DTHREADS=...' to run ant with your build.xml.

Comment: same error as above  
No public execute() in class org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.Arg
If i remove the jvmarg taskdef its showing error like

Problem: failed to create task or type jvmarg
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: Ok. Which version of Jmeter are you using? In my out-of-box Jmeter 2.8 I have **ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar** in %JMETER_HOME%/extras/ dir and NOT **ant-jmeter-1.0.9.jar**. So maybe you've pointed wrong path to the jar and it simply cannot be found? Check this.

Comment: As well you can point anr-jmeter.jar in more general way: <path id="jmeter.classpath"><fileset dir="${jmeter.home}/extras" includes="ant-jmeter*.jar"/></path>

Comment: the error has been removed thanks a lot.but the value is not passed to the jmeter.In jmeter what parameter should i use.to get the value.
Please advice.

Comment: As per sample above I've to use [${__P(jmeter.threads)}](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) (jmeter property, not variable), where 'jmeter.threads' is property you've passed to jmeter in command line.

Comment: Should i do any changes in jmeter still its the thread count is 1 whatever i give

Comment: Looks like I want that somebody solved all the issues for you without any efforts from your side... Well, as per screenshot from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506590/jmeter-properties-overiding you are using [Stepping Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup), right? So as per example above put ${__P(jmeter.threads)} into "This group will start ... threads" field.